AWS Registered Target Port Issue
I am facing an issue with my registered target in AWS and I would like some advice nd guidance please.
Setup: I have a business requirement to have two static IPs for two different availaibity zones. After some research I found I cannot assign an IP directly to a ECS task, but rather I assign an EIP to a NLB and I set it up this way.
So, I have two EIPs: one for eu-west-1a and one for eu-west-1b. Each zone has its own subnet.
The reason for two EIP is, in the event an ECS task fails in eu-west-1a, for example, the new task can be reached via the EIP.
There is also a need for opening custom TCP ports, which is where I am stuck.
I setup a listener for my NLB. The listener has a custom port. I then had to set up a target group for the listener to point to. The target group protocol port was setup with the same custom port as the listener. The health check is set to override to port80.
In my existing cluster, I set up a new task and assigned the NLB, the custom port listener and custom port target group, but the target registered as port 80, not the custom port.
I done some more digging and added the custom port to the task definition, forced a new deployment, and the new ECS task still shows the regsitered target as port 80. If I take the private IP of the ECS task and add it manually with the custom port as a registered target, I can telnet to EIP : custom port. If I don't do this, I cannot telnet.
Where have I gone wrong and why can't the targets register as the custom port?
The network mapping tab in my NLB shows anything to custom port is forwarded to the custom port listener, which is forwarded to the custom port target group. This looks to be setup correctly but when I telnet to EIP : custom port, I get an apache error, which tells me the port is being forwarded to port80.
I tried setting up custom target group and listeners but this did not work. I am stuck. I also updated the task definition to no avail. I am not sure what else to try or test.
